# Reducing the size of .ttf fonts

Tags: text, fonts, font-face, truetype

For my latest projects I've been using @font-face property a lot, and I've embedded several large .ttf fonts to my projects (each of them is >400KB), and I was wondering is there a software that can compress the size of my .ttf fonts or if not compress, than at least to convert in some other format that takes up less bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution that reduces the size of a font, but I've found a software that allows me to see the size of my fonts:
http://xiles.net/downloads/#NexusFont